# Akamai / CDN - How much do CDNs like akamai cost?

Tags: cdn

I haven't been able to find any numbers related to cost via google or price sheets. How much do these services realistically cost (akamai, limelight, any of them)? Are there any good CDN review/comparison sites?

Edit: Just got off the phone with akamai sales - they determine price per client. The cost-per-gb is based off your average expected monthly bandwidth. Hopefully I'll be able to post more details as I get them.

Comment: The costs are pretty clearly outlined on the CDN's websites. It all depends on your actual usage.

Comment: @ESW Thanks, could you link me? I've been reading through akamai's sales brochures, no mention of cost. - http://www.akamai.com/html/solutions/index.html

Comment: I realize this question is really old and the topic is closed, but for what it's worth, high-traffic applications behind Akamai's Edge CDN can cost between $50k-$100k per month.  Obviously, this is based on volume/usage, but this is a price from a real world enterprise scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [this blogpost](http://blog.cloudharmony.com/2010/02/cloud-speed-test-results.html) found on HN that does some benchmarks and
[this website](http://www.cloudclimate.com/cdns) . However (I think) akamai does not, on purpose, list any prices like
many other vendors.
That's because they want you to drop an e-mail to their sales people and sort of claim
that they have an "agreed on" price with each customer.

Realistically IIRC from ~$10c/GB but as I said better drop them an e-mail.

Comment: The embedded link http://blog.cloudharmony.com/2010/02/cloud-speed-test-results.html is dead/unreachable 2023-08-10